# Is there a better way to define multiple boolean variables?

Tags: python, boolean

I have multiple Boolean variables in my code and now they are defined like this:

```
self.paused, self.show_difficulty, self.resizable, self.high_score_saved, \
self.show_high_scores, self.show_game_modes = \
False, False, True, False, False, False
```

And I thought of refactoring the code like this to improve readability.

```
ui_options = {
    "paused": False,
    "show_difficulty": False,
    "resizable": False,
    "high_score_saved": False,
    "show_high_scores": False,
    "show_game_modes": False
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To group values like this, I'd recommend using a dataclass over a dictionary. This means you can still have named attributes rather than needing to do string lookups. This will allow auto-completes and static analyzers to work with your code.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class UIOptions:
    paused: bool = False
    show_difficulty: bool = False
    resizable: bool = False
    high_score_saved: bool = False
    show_high_scores: bool = False
    show_game_modes: bool = False


ui_options = UIOptions()
```

Comment: I really needed something like this! Thank you so much.